# Did Cisco not patch this vulnerability in these modems?

Tags: vulnerability, cisco

I found this article
https://tools.cisco.com/security/center/content/CiscoSecurityAdvisory/Cisco-SA-20120613-CVE-2012-3047

In here are listed vulnerable products, but the list of products that received fixed software is lot shorter.

Does this mean Cisco did not patch vulnerability in those not listed under Fixed Software? Those devices are considered too old to be updated?

Answer (score 4):

The products that aren't being patched are considered EOL (End of Life) or obsolete. Their entire cable modem line, including all the DPXX models, was sold to Technicolor.

You can find more information here: http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en_us/about/ac49/ac0/ac1/ac259/docs/connected-devices.pdf

Comment: I see, so those are considered too old... guess it's time to talk with my ISP of why have they not replaced my old modem then.

Comment: That's weird. Found right now article from Cisco where few of those that were not patched in this post, got patch few years later for something different. So... Cisco did not path old modems for one vulnerability, but patched another vulnerability few years later... honestly, this is confusing.

Comment: In some cases, I have seen them patch the more serious vulnerabilities despite them being EOL. It's rare though. And I don't know the story behind this one as you've not linked the post.